# Win10 Docker Installation of AzerothCore fails to build authserver and worldserver

Tags: docker, azerothcore

Following the [AzerothCore Docker guide](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker#setup) on Windows 10 Pro N using Docker Desktop Version 2.2.0.3 (42716) and I am unable to build the `authserver` and `worldserver` binaries. `docker-compose up` will build the database without issue but cannot find the required files to build the binaries.

`ERROR: for azerothcore-wotlk_ac-authserver_1 Cannot start service ac-authserver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting con
Creating azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1 ... error`

`ERROR: for azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1 Cannot start service ac-worldserver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec \"/azeroth-server/bin/worldserver\": stat /azeroth-server/bin/worldserver: no such file or directory": unknown`

I have system pruned and deleted source and started again. Seems this is destined to fail as it appears they aren't being compiled from the `./bin/acore-docker-build` command - however no error pops up for this either.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I somehow got this working by shifting the `azerothcore-wotlk` folder from my `C:/Users/USERNAME/` folder which is where it defaults to and placing it directly in to my `C:/` - I also had to share my necessary drives with Docker in the `Settings> Resources> File Sharing` tab. I also ran git from the `C:/` with administrator rights. I was able to successfully build using `docker-compose up` however my new issue is that commands written in to the git window while the server is built and active are ignored and do nothing. `Ctrl+C` does however forcibly shut it down.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to h0lysp4nk on the Azerothcore Discord for providing a solution:

1. `git clone` & copy over data files
2. generate and build using `gitbash` in Administrator
3. pull the container IDs with command: `docker ps -a`
4. take acbuild ID and command: `docker cp (acbuildID):/azeroth-server/bin ./acore-build-bin`
5. Copy and setup executables with command: `cp ./acore-build-bin/authserver docker/authserver/bin/authserver && cp ./acore-build-bin/worldserver docker/worldserver/bin/worldserver && chmod +x docker/authserver/bin/authserver && chmod +x docker/worldserver/bin/worldserver`
6. Start containers up with command: `docker-compose up`